# Why does System.out.println() terminate at ASCII Code zero

Tags: java

Try this piece of code -

```
public class WhitespaceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 0;
        char c = (char) x;
        System.out.println("c-->"+c+"<---this doesn't print?");
    }
}
```

The output is -

```
c-->
```

Why does System.out.println() terminate at ASCII code zero?

I tried this in JCreator LE under Windows 7.

Comment: Probably carried over from C-style nul-terminated strings.

Comment: It prints for me. \u0000 is a null character but Java doesn't terminate strings with a null.

Comment: It prints fine for me...

Comment: Maybe it's a Windows OS issue? Or IDE issue?

Comment: It also prints for me. Maybe you've got wrapped System.out? with additional logic :)

Comment: Very interesting -- CodeBlue, on what system are you running the code?  We might find an underlying implementation detail that isn't quite right here...

Comment: @rcook Windows 7. The IDE is JCreator LE.

Comment: does not stop output on Windows/Eclipse

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what your *console* does (or whatever else is handling `System.out`). `System.out` will propagate all the information just fine, and if your console attaches no particular meaning to U+0000 then all will be well. However, many UI controls *will* treat that as a terminating character. This isn't Java's "fault" - it's the UI control itself.

(Just for reference, running that code within a Windows command prompt on Windows 7 is fine for me.)

Comment: OMG it's Jon Skeet! Can't... stop... upvoting!!

Comment: Yes, just I tried it on Windows Command Prompt and it worked there.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ style strings the end of the string is determined by the location of the terminating null-character (the character with value 0, like in your case).  Most likely the `System.out.println()` call passes the string to the OS verbatim, which thinks the string ended at the null-character, and only prints up to that point